# Finding occuramce of a string in a column in excel based text file

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net to find the sum of occuramce of string in a particular column in text file(excel based) . The text file is not tab delimited, and it is separated column by column nicely, I only learnt how to read line by line using stream reader but I have no idea how to read only the last column of the line and summing up the specific string that I want. Any idea how to do it? Not nesseccary nid to provide me the code

Comment: `separated column by column nicely` what in the world does that mean?

Comment: You know, nicely... Like in, not with a tab. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If by "an Excel-based text file" you mean that the values are comma-separated, you can read it in line by line, like you already are doing using a stream, and then use `Split` to separate the line out into an array. Google "vb.net split" to learn how to do this.